# catkin_make won't recognise ROS Package

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm new to ROS and I've been trying to check out the package at the following link: https://github.com/dimatura/loam_continuous. I've cloned it to my catkin workspace but when I try to build the package using

```
catkin_make
```

it doesn't seem to recognise the package. This is my output:

```
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/daniel/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/kinetic
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/kinetic
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/daniel/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.7.4
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/daniel/catkin_ws/build
```

Am I doing something wrong? Could someone please point me in the right direction?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247885/catkin_make-won%27t-recognise-ros-package/) by [cluelessnigerian](https://answers.ros.org/users/28510/cluelessnigerian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-11-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-11**:
Just making sure: the package is in the `/home/daniel/catkin_ws/src` directory?

**Comment by [cluelessnigerian](https://answers.ros.org/users/28510/cluelessnigerian/) on 2016-11-11**:
Yes it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The repository you linked to is not a Catkin package, but a rosbuild one. You cannot build it using `catkin_make`. Only `rosmake` will work.

You either have to find a catkinized version of the package, or build it in a rosbuild workspace.

Note also that the readme explicitly states:

> The program is tested on ROS Fuerte

So apart from the build system, there might be some issues with the code / functionality itself when trying to run it on Kinetic.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cluelessnigerian](https://answers.ros.org/users/28510/cluelessnigerian/) on 2016-11-11**:
Thanks, that makes sense now. I was wondering what `rosmake` was referring to as I'd never come across in all the tutorials I'd come across